# Replacing number by a string (surrounded by doublequotes) with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am running the following powershell commands:

```
powershell -Command "(gc myfile1.json) -replace '1.7976931348623157E308', '""-Infinity""' | Out-File myFile.json"

powershell -Command "(gc myfile1.json) -replace '4.9E-324', '""-Infinity""' | Out-File myFile.json"
```

I get Infinity in my outputfile but I want it to be surrounded by doublequotes -> "Infinity"

How should i procede? I have tried using the following escaping char: `" but I must miss something as this doesnt work either.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm, works for me as expected. When I run `'some random text 1.7976931348623157E308 more random text' -replace '1.7976931348623157E308', '"-Infinity"'` I get `some random text "-Infinity" more random text` as the result.

Comment: Me too, I can't reproduce the problem. What Powershell version are you using?

Comment: This is odd, mine is never surrounded by the quotes in my output file when I tried this. What could lead to this inconsistency ?

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  407

Comment: Try `-replace '1.7976931348623157E308', '"""-Infinity"""'`  (three double quotes inside single quotes) .... or the answer from PlageMan

Answer (score 2):

If you enclose the powershell command with outer double quotes you:

- have to escape the inner double quotes because otherwise cmd.exe will stumble over the pipe symbols - interpreting them itself.
- at the same time you can use one `-replace` RegEx with alternation for both of your replacements

---

```
powershell -NoP -C "(gc myfile1.json) -replace '4.9E-324|1.7976931348623157E308', '\"-Infinity\"' | Out-File myFile.json"
```

Alternatively you can omit the outer double quotes but have to escape the pipe symbol(s) with a caret.

```
powershell -NoP -C (gc myfile1.json) -replace '4.9E-324^|1.7976931348623157E308', '"-Infinity"' ^|Out-File myFile.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's a string pass as a string in the command parameter, you have to add one level of escape :

```
powershell -Command "(gc d:\test.txt) -replace 'x','\""y\""' | out-file D:\result.txt"
```

Edit : the syntax highlighter doesn't like it, but the syntax is correct.

Comment: Are you sure? IMHO `-replace` works with regular expressions only for the match - not for the actual replace - that's literal.

Comment: @Olaf, I'm never sure of nothing :) , the problem is not on the replace command itself, but how to preserve the quotes inside the command parameter.

Comment: @PlageMan When I run  `'some random text ' -replace 'x','\""y\""' ` I get as result this: `some random te\""y\""t` .   ;-)  If you don't use variables or back references from the match the replace text is literal. So single quotes surrounding double quotes should preserve the double quotes prefectly.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, but if you run **powershell -Command** "'some random text ' -replace 'x','\""y\""'" , now you have some random te"y"t

Comment: @PlageMan  ... Ahhh ... now I see what you mean. I was testing from inside Powershell. So I've learned something today. Thanks.  ;-)   ....  This works as well:  `powershell -Command "& {'some random text ' -replace 'x','"""y"""'}"`

Comment: @Olaf, My explanations sucks because my english is very limited, i should have put in my answer the command parameter help text where they talk about this problem.

Comment: @PlageMan Don't worry. I think for most of the colleagues here english is at least the second or third language.